# Как упростить конструкцию вывода из БД PHP?

Tags: php, html, база-данных, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Есть конструкция вида:

```
     If($y['kabala'] == "Легкая")                     echo '<img>Хорошая.жпег</img>';
     elseif ($y['kabala'] == "Тяжелая")               echo '<img>Плохая.жпег</img>';  
     elseif ($y['kabala'] == "Страшная")              echo '<img>Злая.жпег</img>';

     elseif ($y['kabala'] == "ЛегкаяТяжелая")         echo '<img>Хорошая.жпег</img> <img>Плохая.жпег</img>';  

     elseif ($y['kabala'] == "ЛегкаяТяжелаяСтрашная") echo '<img>Злая.жпег</img> <img>Плохая.жпег</img> <img>Злая.жпег</img>';
```

То есть, при совпадении: выводит вариант картинок ( одну, или несколько).
Данные в базе записаны в виде различных комбинаций(без пробела).

Таких комбинаций более 20.

Будет ли лучше, если в БД будет не одно поле "Kabala" а например отдельно: Kabala1, Kabala2 и т.д,  и Просто выводить при совпадении, иначе НИЧЕГО?

Какие еще более простые варианты можете предложить?
Спасибо!

Comment: Как минимум, посмотреть в сторону шаблонизаторов.

Comment: Ну если уж крайний случай, то можно сделать через массив и цикл

Comment: две таблицы 1) kabala id|name 2) kabala_img kabala_id|url
и выгребаете все картинки по всем кабалам вашим )

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так

Таблица справочник

```
CREATE TABLE kabalaDict(
    kabalaId BYTE,
    kabala VARCHAR,
    jpegName VARCHAR
)
```

Таблица связи какой-то вашей сущности с разными kabala'ми

```
CREATE TABLE kabala(
    entityId INT,
    kabalaId BYTE
)
```

В коде вычитываете справочник

```
$kabalaDictRaw = $dbLink
     ->query('SELECT kabalaId, jpegName FROM kabalaDict')
     ->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$kabalaDict = [];
foreach($kabalaDictRaw as $kabala){
    $kabalaDict[$kabala['kabalaId']] = $kabala['jpegName'];
}
```

Получаем данные по своей сущности и печатаем html

```
$currentKabala = $dbLink
    ->query('SELECT kabalaId FROM kabala')
    ->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 1);
foreach($currentKabala as $kabala){
    echo '<img>'.$kabalaDick[$kabala].'</img>';
}
```